# Laravel 5.5 Send Mail with Sendmail driver CentOS - (Outgoing) Connection timed out

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail

I'm trying to send emails with sendmail driver but it isn't working and I got no errors.

My `.env` file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

My `mail.php` file:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'sendmail'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', ''),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'no-reply@inspvirtual.mx'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'INSP Virtual'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', null),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Since I got no errors, even in laravel.log file I don't know even where to start checking, I have checked for the correct sendmail path though, and it was correct, what am I missing?

I also read that you have to change some things in /etc/hosts I changed it a bit adding "inspvirtual.mx", but I'm not quite sure if this is correct:

```
127.0.0.1   inspvirtual.mx
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

The maillog prints out this after I try to send an email:

```
May 26 14:12:35 inspvirtual sendmail[3130]: x4Q9BDjB010067: to=<aaron@juicyboom.com>, delay=09:01:22, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1020554, relay=mail.juicyboom.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with mail.juicyboom.com.
May 26 14:12:35 inspvirtual sendmail[3130]: x4Q9BWIJ010111: to=<aaron@juicyboom.com>, delay=09:01:03, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1020554, relay=mail.juicyboom.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with mail.juicyboom.com.
May 26 14:12:35 inspvirtual sendmail[3130]: x4Q9CdaV010235: to=<aaron@juicyboom.com>, delay=08:59:56, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1020554, relay=mail.juicyboom.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with mail.juicyboom.com.
May 26 14:12:35 inspvirtual sendmail[3130]: x4Q9Nnob011458: to=<aaron@juicyboom.com>, delay=08:48:46, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1020554, relay=mail.juicyboom.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with mail.juicyboom.com.
May 26 14:12:35 inspvirtual sendmail[3130]: x4Q8pH0A007887: to=<aaron.070194@gmail.com>, delay=09:21:18, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1020560, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
May 26 14:12:35 inspvirtual sendmail[3130]: x4Q8rkK3008160: to=<aaron.070194@gmail.com>, delay=09:18:49, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1020560, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
May 26 14:12:35 inspvirtual sendmail[3130]: x4Q8TUXJ005341: to=<aaron.070194@gmail.com>, delay=09:43:05, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1110560, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
May 26 14:12:35 inspvirtual sendmail[3130]: x4Q8Wnpn005708: to=<aaron.070194@gmail.com>, delay=09:39:46, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1110560, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
May 26 14:12:35 inspvirtual sendmail[3130]: x4Q8bZaD006249: to=<aaron.070194@gmail.com>, delay=09:35:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1110560, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
May 26 14:12:35 inspvirtual sendmail[3130]: x4Q8fPQg006712: to=<aaron.070194@gmail.com>, delay=09:31:10, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1110560, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

It's important to say that I configure manually all of the necessary stuff on this server in order to work since this is a dedicated server, like the DNS for example.

I have also changed the `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` file, in this line:

```
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`inspvirtual.mx')dnl
```

I have also run `hostname` to check if the hostname is correct and it prints out the correct one: `inspvirtual.mx`

I'm very new in configuring from 0 a server manually so I'm a little bit lost here...

Comment: Your outgoing email connections are being blocked. Contact your IT department to have the firewall checked or to find out if a relay host is required.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have root access on server, can I fix this by my own?

Comment: No, you cannot fix this on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [MichaelHampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton) suggested
**IF** all out messages stay in queue with `connection timed out`
**THEN** most likely your outgoing SMTP connections are blocked (firewalled out) e.g. by your ISP or your intranet firewall

Suggested verification procedure:
1. Check if you get SMTP greeting message [Is it sendmail fault?]
`telnet mail.juicyboom.com 25`
2. use tools like `tcptraceroute` to locate firewall location